# bounding box for creating collision pairs in c#

Tags: c#, cad

I am looking for the creating collision pairs.

**What I have:**

- .stl files

Each stl file has one machine object.

When I load these files in a CAD tool (MachineBuilder_ModuleWOrks) I can see a complete machine in 3D.

Now i need to check for collision pair. I have come across Bounding boxes concept. But I still don't understand how it works.

I'm trying to code in c# visual studio(I'm adding an extra feature of collision pair detection in that tool).

Any ideas or code sample in c# would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made a search, what have you tried ?

Comment: Look at Wiki article and the "See Also" links : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection

Comment: A bounding box is simply the smallest square or cube usually aligned on your axis that contains your object. Collision detection then first checks collisions on the bounding boxes because that is much easier than testing a million triangles against each other.

Comment: @Severiano - I have read upon bounding boxes in 3D, SAP algorithm , wiki suggested above. I haven't found any good sources in the implementation part.